# Primary Key Violation Java Spring Boot SQL Server

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, sql-update

In my project I have Events entity and MyLocation entity.

MyLocation id is the event.eventStartTime (ISOString) + event.eventName, and
I am having trouble when I am trying to update the event name (not related to the MyLocation String name anymore), this is the error:

```
 Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__my_locat__72E12F1A88A314B4'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.my_location'. The duplicate key value is (2020-06-25T14:00:01.235ZWeddingT&Z).
```

This is the code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Events")
public class Event {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long eventID;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String eventName;
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private MyLocation eventLocation;
    @column
    private TimeStamp eventStartTime;
    ....
```

```
@Entity
public class MyLocation {
    @Id
    private String name;
    @Column
    private double longitude;
    @Column
    private double latitude;
    .....
```

Is the problem related to the @Id in MyLocation?
or any other solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your are trying to make a duplicate entry of MyLocation.
How are you generating the location name or are you having sufficient checking logic on location name that is unique?

Also you may have some other type as primary key of event table. like uuid.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = “UUID”)
    @GenericGenerator(
        name = “UUID”,
        strategy = “org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator”,
    )
@Column(name = “id”, updatable = false, nullable = false)
private UUID id;
```

Or you can have an auto-increment id:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;
```

Comment: the location name is the timestamp+eventName as string, so i dont really know what is the problem with my code. when i am using the update method on an event, what is the effect over the MyLocation object in event?

Comment: It's part of the event entity. So everytime you save event ,location table will be updated . Btw why does the location id have to be event name + timestamp. It means for same event you will have multiple locations (at different times) which is a violation coz u defined one to one mapping

Comment: the ID it dosen't have to be this String i can use any other generated number ill change that, but that wont change i think.                     
maybe the relationship definition is wrong? I just want every event to have its own location, with the option to update the event or the location simply.